How to order properties of a custom component
I am writing a custom component (a colored BindNavigator)

But for Hints sub-properties, I am blocked.
   TBtnsHints = class (TPersistent)
  private
    FOwner : TColoredBindNavigator;
    FButtonHints : TButtonHints;
    function GetHint(const index : Integer) : String;
    function HintisStored(const index: Integer) : Boolean;
    procedure SetHint(const index : Integer; const Value : String) ;
   public
    constructor Create(aOwner : TColoredBindNavigator);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property _1First : String index 0 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _2Prior : String index 1 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _3Next : String index 2 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _4Last : String index 3 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _5Insert : String index 4 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _6Delete : String index 5 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _7Edit : String index 6 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _8Post : String index 7 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property _9Cancel : String index 8 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property __0Refresh : String index 9 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property __1ApplyUpdate : String index 10 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
    property __2CancelUpdate : String index 11 read GetHint write SetHint stored HintisStored;
  end;

I want to have a logical order  ('First','Prior', ....., 'CancelUpdates')
The only way I found is to use a prefix '_n' but I find this unsatisfactory.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Properties are streamed to/from the DFM in the order that they are declared. But, the Object Inspector displays properties in alphabetical order and you can't change that.

I understood that but was hoping a sort of property sort order, in the same idea you can write a CustomPropertyEditor.

There is no custom property sort order. Properties are listed alphabetical. However, since your properties are already in a TPersistent class, you might be able to implement a custom TPropertyEditor for TBtnsHints that overrides the virtual GetProperties() method to provide editors for each sub-property in the order you want the OI to display them in. But that is a lot of work just for sorting.

Yes, I realized this, working on this yesterday ! Especially since all my work was lost following poor handling on my part (compiling/installing a component will not save the files, unlike an application?).
Never mind, I learned something (custom editors) so I'll persevere ;-)
